# How to remove this flow restrictor in hansgrohe hand shower?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have a [hand shower](https://pro.hansgrohe-usa.com/articledetail-croma-select-e-handshower-110-3-jet-1-75-gpm-04723400) which has a [flow restrictor](https://assets.hansgrohe.com/mam/celum/celum_assets/16__hrgi0202_pdf.pdf) in it. I've found other flow restrictors easier to remove than this one. The metal tabs seem to bite into the plastic pretty hard (making it probably easy to insert, but hard to remove). There is also nowhere really good to grip with pliers. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: the obvious thing is to bend the tabs

Comment: @jsotola yeah it would seem so. Not even sure what kind of tool to use... it is **really** tight in there.

Comment: needle nose pliers.

Comment: Should be able to bend them with a small screwdriver.

Comment: Wonder what would happen if you drilled out the plastic center piece....

Comment: use a tip of a thin knife to bend the tabs ... a straightened paper clip might also work

Comment: Not a nice knife though!  Easy to wreck a point or edge that way!  I'd go with a dental pick or jewelry pliers.  They also look like flush cut type wire cutters could probably snip them, although if it's particularly hard metal you could wreck your cutters.  Could also bend a hook or 6 hooks or loops out of tie wire and probably pull it that way.

Comment: I would try a small piece of strong wire bent to a sharp 90 degree angle and hook it behind the grips of the ring and loosen each one, or distort it enough to release it.

Answer (score 2):

To collect the comments into an answer:

Use a small piece of metal to lift/bend each of the metal prongs up so it's no longer pressing into the plastic on the outside, holding the flow restrictor in place. Consider using one or more of the following to do so:

- A small dental-type pick<sup>*</sup>
- A small screw driver
- A hefty paperclip
- A sturdy piece of wire bent into a hook

You might have to push the restrictor slightly down while pulling up on the tab to release the end of the tab from where it's seated into the plastic. Simply pulling up may actually work against you to further embed the tab into the plastic wall.

It appears that there are 6 tabs holding it in place, once you get 3 of them bent, there will likely be enough play to get it out without having to bend the rest of them.

If you're finding it difficult to get the tabs to bend, you may consider leaving the restrictor in place and simply drilling out the plastic center, thus reducing the restriction. If you do this, be sure to thoroughly rinse out nozzle before reinstalling it. You want to be sure to get all the plastic swarf out the large end instead of letting it clog up the shower head.

<sup>*</sup>A pick like one of these:

[image] [image]

<sup>Images courtesy of Harbor Freight, where the items depicted are available for under $5 US. No particular recommendation made, though they are a good source of cheap stuff. Neither an employee, owner, nor stock holder, but I'm always thrilled when my purchases last for a 2nd use!</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I used locking forceps (like the AmScope 6 in. Serrated Tip College Forceps with Lock) - something I picked up at a flea market a million years ago and is one of the most useful tools I own.  With these (very fine needle tip), I was able to get under and grab one tab strongly enough to pull the retainer in one shot.  The restrictor itself is also difficult to extract, especially if the head (or handshower) has been used.  I suppose the water pressure packs the restrictor in there pretty tight.

I did 4 Clubmaster heads and 3 handshowers recently.  By the last one, it was taking no more than a few minutes to extract.